# Google groups : how to retrieve list of members through email

Tags: google-groups

As the owner of a group (Google Group), is there a way to send an email to my group with a special key so that I get back the list of members?

Some mailing list have an admin interface through email. For example with mailman you send an email to `listname-request@domain` with a command such as `who` to get back the list of subscribers. Is there any such feature with Google Groups?

Comment: What is the use case? Could you post why that is a requirement to do this through email - it could clarify the question.

Comment: This question was so strange, I had to look into it... I think however, the answer is no - and yes... No - because there seems to be no automated mechanism to do it, and yes - using a special token in the email body: `Hey $otherAdmin, would you mind sending the list of members to me? Thanks a lot, $myName`, of course with the right substitutions... However this latter needs to be sent to another admin - and not the group...